# Git - pre-commit hook error color

Tags: git, stdout, stderr, pre-commit-hook

My pre-commit hook compresses/compiles css/js files. When an error occurs, I simply use `echo` to output the error and then `exit 1`. However, the text that's written to the console is **WHITE** so it's not easy to see when an error occurs.

Is there another way to write to the console (errOut?) that will make the text **RED**?

Comment: Add your pre-commit-hook script to your question.

Comment: All you need is a 3 line pre-commit hook that looks like this: 
`#!/usr/bin/sh[NEXTLINE]>&2 echo "JS compression failed"[NEXTLINE]exit 1` where NEXTLINE is a new line

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Best way to deal with this is to colorize your hook output instead of the PS1 prompt, like so:

```
red='\033[0;31m'
green='\033[0;32m'
yellow='\033[0;33m'
no_color='\033[0m'

echo -e "\n${yellow}Executing pre-commit hook${no_color}\n"

... do your hook stuff ...

if [[ something bad happens ]]; then
    >&2 echo -e "\n${red}ERROR - Something BAD happened!\n${no_color}"
    exit 1
fi

echo -e "${green}Git hook was SUCCESSFUL!${no_color}\n"
```

Note: Using `-e` with `echo` is required - it specifies to interpret special characters, like colors and new lines. (http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to customize you bash, like this:

```
0 ;) $ cat ~/.bashrc
PS1="\[\033[01;37m\]\$? \$(if [[ \$? == 0 ]]; then echo \"\[\033[01;32m\];)\"; else echo \"\[\033[01;31m\];(\"; fi) $(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo
 '\[\033[01;31m\]\h'; else echo '\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h'; fi)\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] "
```

It displays a green happy face ;) if the last command finished with no errors, and a red sad face ;( if it failed, for example:

```
0 ;) $ cat 1.sh
#!/bin/bash
exit 1
0 ;) $ ./1.sh
1 ;( $ 
0 ;( $ cat 1.sh
#!/bin/bash
exit 0
0 ;) $ ./1.sh
0 ;) $
```

You can customize the output however you want.

The example was taken from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Return_value_visualisation)

In action:
[image]

**Update**

For Git 2.5 for windows it should be

```
if ! \$?; then
  PS1="\[\e[1;32m\]Nice Work!\n\[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[0;37m\]\n\$ " 
else
  PS1="\[\e[1;31m\]Something is wrong!\n\[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[0;37m\]\n\$ "
fi
```

Comment: Thank you @zaratustra - I'm trying to understand your example. Can you edit and add an explanation of what the commands are doing? I'm pretty limited in my shell scripting. I have no idea what `0 ;) $ cat 1.sh` does.

Comment: The `cat` command prints on the screen the content of a file. In this case the `1.sh` file is a bash script that exits with a error(`exit 1`) in first case and after editing it the script finishes successfully(`exit 0`)

Comment: Can I do this without creating new sh script files? Maybe all I need to do is write to stderr? I assume echo writes to stdout... how would I write to stderr?

Comment: I tried `>&2 echo "JS compression failed"` but that still prints in white.

Comment: If you take a look at `.bashrc` you might notice that it uses `$?`, aka the exit code of the previous command. So if you direct the output to stderr bash won't colorize the bash as you expect. You need to set the exit code explicitly in your hook (`exit 0` or `exit 1`)

Comment: I am doing that... I'm calling `exit 1` just after I write the error.

Comment: No, it writes to the console in white.

Comment: It works [well](http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/08/e94c03e5b7da044303d3dc699c4dbcd6.jpg) for me

Comment: Can you post a simple pre-commit hook that writes in red and then `exit 1`

Comment: you can take a look at the screenshot and find my sample of a pre-commit hook. It is at the bottom of the picture

Comment: I don't see your screenshot or the sample pre-commit hook (@zaratustra). Where did you post it? I would love to give you credit for this answer if I can make it work!!! :)

Comment: Thanks @zaratustra, I'm sorry, but I'm still not getting it. I can see your output, and I can see your precomit-hook, which seems simple, but I don't understand how you output the red or green faces.

Comment: It is in the `.bashrc` if you take a closer look you will find the faces there. The idea: if the code if the previous operation is 0 (success) `if [[ \$? == 0 ]]` then bash displays a green face `\"\[\033[01;32m\];)\"` otherwise bash displays a red face `\"\[\033[01;31m\];(\"` the rest of the command is just to show who you are and what computer you use.

Comment: Thanks... now I know why I don't get it. What does it mean to "customize you bash" and how do I do that? I can't find `.bashrc` in either my git repo or the git program folder and when you said "Take a look at .bashrc" I can't seem to do that.

Comment: `.bashrc` is a `bash`'s config file. Usually it resides in your home directory(~). You are allowed to create a new one if you haven't had one yet, so type `vim ~/.bashrc` (or `nano` or whatever editor you use) and add this string in it.

Comment: Finally! This took way too long, but hey, I learned something! Brought me back to my college days using vim. Here's what I came up with that looks identical to gitbash colors, and only adds a red "whoops" before the prompt if the previous command didn't exit 0. `PS1="\$(if [[ \$? == 1 ]]; then echo \"\[\e[1;31m\]Whoops!\"; fi)\n\[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[0;37m\]\n\$"`

Comment: I just updated to Git 2.5.3 and selected to use the mintty terminal, and now my PS1 no longer works. I get the error "syntax error near unexpected token ')' and then it just echos everything past the first echo without executing the conditional. Any ideas how I would rewrite the expression for the Cygwin mintty terminal?

Comment: I figured it out... should be:
`if ! \$?; then
 PS1="\[\e[1;32m\]Nice Work!\n\[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[0;37m\]\n\$ "
else
 PS1="\[\e[1;31m\]Shit Damn!\n\[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[0;37m\]\n\$ "
fi
`

Comment: I thought I had this working, but `if ! \$?; then` always returns true, so the prompt is always green. I tried several ways to test if an error happens, but I can't figure it out.